# About the verb "fold"

Tags: verbs

I came across the sentence "The person folded the school". A dictionary say the usage of "fold" in this meaning is intransitive like " The school folded" but this "fold" is used as transitive.

So Is "The person folded the school" wrong ? Or "fold" can be used as transitive like this?

In addition I guess "The person folded the school" means "The person closed the English school."

And Is "The person folded the company" correct? Does it means "The person closed the company."? A dictionary only say "The company fold."

Comment: *fold* can be used both transitive or intransitive. In this case the person *folded [something]*, but I think the sentence is weird. It probably means another thing.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard it used in this way, and did not understand what your example was intended to mean until I read your following sentence. Having said that, I think if the example was "He folded the company", I would probably have understood it, because I think of a company as something that can go bust ('fold') more readily than I think of a school that way.

The OED gives 'fold' as only intransitive with that meaning (of course it can be transitive with other meanings).

So, I would hesitate to say that any usage is "wrong", but that usage is outside my experience, and not easy for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language gives the meaning of *fold* tr. *

> Informal To discontinue operating; close: They had to fold the company a year after they started it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually school are **closed** whereas companies can be **folded** or **closed**.

> Many schools were **closed** due to budget cuts.
>   The company filed for bankruptcy and **folded**.

Your use of **fold** means to **discontinue** or **stop** doing something

The term is also commonly used in card games, especially **poker** where a player can
raise (increase the betting), call (match the betting) , or **fold** (stop playing, and lose their stake).

In the same way, when a company **folds**, it is usually due to **financial difficulty** instead of for various other reasons when the use of **close** may be more appropriate.

> Drexel Burnham spectacularly **folded** due to junk bonds in the 1990's.
>
> The Somerdale Factory near Bristol was **closed** by Kraft foods in 2011 when production was moved to Poland.

Usually a third person will **close** a company, whereas a legal entity or owner may **fold** a company.

Comment: Have you any evidence for the transitive use of "fold" in your last sentence, Peter? I don't believe I've ever heard it.

Comment: In conversation "he folded his company", "his company folded".  "Mr. Jones was going broke, so he folded his business up"[here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fold+up) is an on-line example, but that's **folded up**, which I've not heard used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems intransitive use is more common than the transitive one,